# Low Variable Matrix Search No Results

Tags: matrix, low-variables

I'm having a bear of a time with what I thought would be a simple conditional. I've got a Low Variables Matrix field with several dates and custom messages. Basically the client wants to use these dates to remove their phone number on holidays and have a custom message like "Closed today - Merry Christmas!."

Here's what I'm using for testing:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var='lv_holiday_message' search:date='04/08/16'}
{if '{total_rows}' == '1'}
 {holiday_message}
    {if:else}
    TEST
    {/if}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

The first conditional always works - if one of the date columns matches the search date then my custom message gets shown. But I can't for the life of me figure out what conditional shows something when a date DOESN'T match. I've tried if:else's , total rows == 0 or empty, checking for data on just the date column itself, if no_results and it never return a my TEST text.

Am I missing something simple or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more? 
If the date matches it shows {holiday_message}. Its correct.
But if the date doesn't match does it shows holiday_message ??
I mean to say whatever be the date does it shows the holiday_message. It means it always goes in first if.
If that is the case you can try below -

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var='lv_holiday_message' search:date='04/08/16'}
   {if total_rows == '1'}
       {holiday_message}
   {if:else}
       TEST
   {/if}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If this doesn't work you can try using -

```
{if total_rows == 1}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Like my original post said, I tried total_rows, no_results, etc... but nothing worked. Sent a message directly to Pixel and Tonic and they sent me an updated copy of Matrix that allowed the {if no_results} tag to work again. There was a small bug in the version I had.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a small bug in Matrix causing the {if no_results} tag to stop parsing. Pixel and Tonic got me an updated version (2.6.2) and that allowed me to use the tag correctly.